# Putting background image on matplotlib's radar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

Such image above is what I could get from using matplotlib.

Is it possible to use a background image instead of using fixed color?

I am looking to get something like this.

[image]

Comment: It should be possible using the shape you obtain from the plot as a `clip_path` of an image. The more you share of what you have tried the higher the chances to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest would it be possible for you to show a simple example? What I've only learned is doing `ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="group A")` and
`ax.fill(angles, values, 'r', alpha=0.1)` to fill the color.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It will be really nice if you could give me some more hints. I still can't figure out what do I have to do..